# Assign each button in DataGridView to open a different Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` where it shows the plays from a MS access database, at the moment I am trying to know how to assign each button to do something different like showing a new form or a message box.

this the code

```
    private void btnShowPlays_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();

        try
        {               
            myConnection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = myConnection;
            string query = "select * from plays";
            command.CommandText = query; 


            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView.DataSource = dt;

            DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            dataGridView.Columns.Add(btn);
            btn.HeaderText = "Options";
            btn.Name = "More Info";
            btn.Text = "More Info";
            btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

            myConnection.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception in DBHandler" + ex);
        }

    }
```

I tried this

```
     private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex==2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show((e.RowIndex+1).ToString() +" Information");
        }
    }
```

i think something is wrong with it but what Im trying to do is to let each button on every row to show a different Form or a message box.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Can you add how you are deciding whether to show a message or display a form or some other action, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something along these lines should solve your problem:

```
private void dataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var gridView = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (gridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
        e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        //TODO: Button was clicked. Check the index of the row and do you specialized work for different rows.
    }
}
```

Thats the code for the event, you have to bind that to the datagrid and write the switch/ifs using the rowIndex to have different functionality for each button.

Hope it helps!

---

Added after reading extra comments and edition made on original question:

```
private void dataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var gridView = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (gridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
        e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        string typeOfRow = gridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2 /*Column that defines the type of action to take*/].ToString();
        if (typeOfRow == "ShowMessage")
        {
            // Here i just copied the logic you added, dont know if it makes sense. 
            MessageBox.Show((e.RowIndex + 1).ToString() + " Information");

            //I would assume you want to do this instead:
            MessageBox.Show((gridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3/*number of column with data to show*/]).ToString() + " Information");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: one more question how do i check the index for each row to let it do different function. still new to coding. thank you

Comment: No problem. You would do that with the parameter e.RowIndex that contains the Index of the row that was clicked and fired the event. You would need to have a way to identify the record and "type" of action to take based on that index.

Comment: would you be able to provide an example please?

Comment: I´m adding more logic to the anwser. Please verify if it helps clarifying how it works. The idea is to use the dataGridView having the e.RowIndex that was clicked and then access the cells you need using the index of the column you want.

Comment: sorry for late relpy, just managed to try what you did and played a bit with the code but i end up with the same message for each row except that the row number would change.